# GraphQL - Warning: rename .....access denied

Tags: php, apache, symfony, graphql, windows-10

my local GraphQL backend throws Internal server errors, when I try to fetch stuff from the DB. The live environment which is identical runs without those errors. In the chrome DevTools under Network GraphQL outputs following debug message when I try to fetch the data from the frontend (ionic):

debugMessage: "Warning: rename(D:\pathToLocalBackendFolder\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__AppEntityProperty.php.6058d378460452.39776425,D:\pathToLocalBackendFolder\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__AppEntityProperty.php): Zugriff verweigert (code: 5)"

"Zugriff verweigert" translates to "Access denied"

The backend is Symfony 5.1. And I run a local apache server with Wampserver64 under **Windows10 Pro**.
The apache hosts my backend with SSL (wasn't easy to setup) but the problem persists also when I create a virtualhost without SSL.
It does seem to fetch all the data anyways but I would like to fix those error messages anyways, because later on it could stab me in the back.

What I tried so far to resolve it:

- Write *umask(0000);* in the beginning of bin/console and public/index.php
- Run the wampapache64 and wampmysqld64 services as a local admin user (tested the renaming functionality of the specific files by logging in as that user. So the user I let the services run from has all the necessary permissions. Also I double checked by echoing 'whoami' from within GraphQL. It was the correct user I specified before.)
- Gave the var/cache folder and all subfolder and all subfiles full permission (via chmod command and also via Windows folder properties)
- Cleared the cache (var/cache) of symfony a couple of times. Sometimes with php bin/console cache:clear or even by deleting tha content manually
- I did try everything I could from that link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html
- And I also checked out this link and try to apply it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

What can I try next?

Comment: The file you have problems with, is generated automatically by Doctrine ORM. Does it work if you take the prod setting [`auto_generate_proxy_classes: false`](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/1.12/config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml#L3) and instead generate the proxies via `bin/console`? If not, your current approach seems to be correct. You have to set the write permissions for the cache dir, so that you CLI user and your web user can write to it. CLI user because the caches might be generated via commands, e.g. after a `composer install`

Comment: @dbrumann That worked! Thank you for the tip. I did read about it before but did not try it out, because doctrine warned about setting that option to false in dev env: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/advanced-configuration.html#auto-generating-proxy-classes-optional 
I am willing to try it out though and see if there are problems that will occur. I am still uncertain when exactly I have to use the generate-proxies command? Everytime I do changes in the db/doctrine?

Comment: Yes, any change to your entity classes will probably require a rebuild, which is not optimal for development, but I am not sure why the auto generated proxies don't have the right permissions either